# If there are verses that says we need to follow prophet (pbuh) then what does this verses 5:48 also another one that says "Quran is the best hadith"

Tags: quran, hadith

I just need to know whether we need hadith when it comes to interpretation. Some said to avoid several views.

Also what does Quran mean when it says hadith? Does it actually refer to Prophet's statement? Or does it say something figuratively?

Quran is clear in statement. But does that mean we will take it literally and  that means we need hadiths?

Comment: "Hadith" in the corresponding verse rather means "speech" or "word" as it refers to Alalh's words. And this is how it is translated please quote the full verse and reference. You should know that I've answered some questions of qur'anists earlier, but as their posts were deleted my answers are also deleted.

Comment: Before "medisaif answers this" , you need know that you need to quote the translation of [5:48](https://quran.com/al-maidah/48)(the other one also) and kindly ask one question at a time. **I cannot find  "Quran is the best Hadith "translation anywhere.**

Comment: @Medi1Saif.  It's verse no 45:6 from this site sahih international...  https://legacy.quran.com/45.    These are the verses of Allah which We recite to you in truth. Then in what statement after Allah and His verses will they believe?

Comment: حَدِيثٍۭ means message or statement

Comment: @cenyviik I can request quote both the Quran references but I still can't understand what relationship do they have with following Mohamed pbuh .

Comment: @AbduRahman the question is if Quran says on what statement after Allah and His verses will they believe... does this mean were also not supposed to Follow hadith?

Comment: @cenyviik I suggest reading: https://blog.fussilat.com/incoherence-of-sunnah-rejection/